# Ethernet nodemcu

Tags: ethernet, nodemcu, home-automation, iot

I have a question that might be a #noob question but I am wondering if there is a board similar to the nodemcu in size that runs arduino code but instead can use ethernet to connect to the network instead of the wifi? I have already seen the connections to use one of the pins and such to connect that way but I am looking to see if there is a board that has the rj45 connection on it already.

Comment: closest I found is MKR Zero with MKR ETH shield

Comment: while I can't categorically rule it out, I've never seen such a device after hundreds of hours shopping different sites and buying about 15 different models of ESP boards over 2 years...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you'll find a single off-the-shelf product.  The closest I have managed to come to it is a [Teensy 3.2](https://www.pjrc.com/store/teensy32.html) plus a [WIZ820io & Micro SD Card Adaptor](https://www.pjrc.com/store/wiz820_sd_adaptor.html) and a [WIZ850io module](http://www.wiznet.co.kr/product-item/wiz850io/), all stacked together.  Footprint-wise it's around the same as (or smaller than) many ESP8266-based boards - however it's considerably chunkier when all combined:

[image]

Comment: Awesome. Thanks all of these are great staring places for me. Thanks so much

Comment: "it's considerably chunkier". it is only the RJ-45 connector.

Answer (score -1):

Yes one does exist that I know of. It's called the [EtherTen](https://www.freetronics.com.au/products/etherten) and is made by an Australian company called Freetronics.

[image: EtherTen]

It uses the ATMega328P microcontroller that is used on the Arduino Uno. It is 100% Arduino compatible with onboard (RJ45 wired) Ethernet.

It can be purchased from [Freetronics.com.au](https://www.freetronics.com.au/products/etherten) or from [Roboshop.com](https://www.robotshop.com/en/etherten-ethernet-arduino-compatible-microcontroller.html).

Freetronics provides a number of documents and resources on the page linked above.

Comment: this is Arduino Ethernet clone. how is this similar to NodeMCU? it is not 32bit and is large.

Comment: The requirement was that it runs Arduino code. There was no requirement that it had to be 32-bit nor be compatible with NodeMCU (except for size).